# Tkinter - Grid elements next to each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make some UI in python with tkinter.

This is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x700x0x0")

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 700, height = 700, bg ='white').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
button1 = Button(root, text = "w/e", command = w/e).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
button2 = Button(root, text = "w/e", command = w/e).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

This is what i'm getting:[image]

and this is what I want:[image]

Any help on how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: use `grid(rowspan=...)` for canvas or put `Frame` in right column and put buttons in this frame.

Comment: BTW: `var = Widgets().grid()` assigns `None` to `var` because `grid()` returns `None`. If you will need variables then do it in two steps: `var = Widget()` and `var.grid()`.

Comment: The `grid(rowspan=...)` solved it, thank you @furas

Comment: You should separate the canvas and the buttons into different `Frames`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your GUI seems to have two logical groups of widgets, I would organize it as such. Start by placing the canvas on the left and a frame on the right. You can use `pack`, `place`, `grid`, or a paned window to manage them. For a left-to-right orientation, `pack` is a good choice due to its simplicity

Note that you don't have to do it this way, but experience has taught me it makes layout problems much easier to solve.

In the following example I set `expand` to `False` for the button frame, which means that the canvas will grow and shrink when the user resizes (because it has `expand=True`), but the buttons will only take up exactly as much space as they need.

```
canvas = Canvas(root, ...)
buttonframe = Frame(root, ...)

canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
buttonframe.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=False)
```

Next, you can put all of the buttons in the right side without having to worry how their placement might affect objects on the left.

The important thing to remember when using `grid` is that you should designate at least one row and at least one column to be given any extra space. This can be a row and/or column that contains widgets, or it can be an empty row and column on an edge.

```
button1 = Button(buttonframe, ...)
button2 = Button(buttonframe, ...)
button3 = Button(buttonframe, ...)
...
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0)
...
buttonframe.grid_rowconfigure(100, weight=1)
buttonframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

---

note: if you need to keep a reference to a widget, you must create the widget and call `grid` (or `pack` or `place`) on two separate lines. This is because `Button(...).grid(...)` returns the value of the last function call, and `grid(...)` returns `None`

Comment: Thanks for all your answers Bryan. Whenever there's a question about `tkinter` you always seem to have an answer!